# ULN2003 IC , should I stack it or should I divide the load?

Tags: transistors, power, heat, overheat, transistor-array

I am trying to drive 7 led strips.

I saw in the datasheet that the ULN2003 IC can supply 500mA per channel. In reality this would be limited due to heat dissipation by the IC.

Should I drive 3 led strips on 1 IC and 4 on the other, or should I stack it to increase overall current and divide the heat dissipation?

Each strip takes around 400mA at 12 volts.

Comment: Use [one of these](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl7407la.pdf?ts=1598887142304&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPL7407LA). instead (TPL7407L) - it won't produce anything like the heat because it switches on with a much lower volt drop. Farnell link: https://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/tpl7407ldr/driver-mosfet-low-side-soic-16/dp/3118831?MER=NULLSEARCH_VB_PD

Comment: I would just use them to drive a nice low RDS pfet per channel and not play the mA games

Comment: You really should switch to a modern driver. The ULN2003A was the best we had in the 1980s for a project and, my goodness, the characteristics and losses were painful then. Thirty years later, they're to be avoided at all costs (except where costs insist, naturally). Are you stuck with it, is it part of a board you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the ULN2003 at all, rather use a decent logic-level MOSFET. That's only 2.8A which is no problem for a MOSFET such as a IRLB4132PbF.

The Darlington switches in the ULN2003 drop a lot of voltage and thus get hot.

If you insist on using it, refer to figure 5 in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf?ts=1598887219319&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), each unit can only drive a single 400mA strip at 100% duty cycle. You should not parallel outputs that are not in the same package so you would really need 7 ULN2003, one for each strip.

Comment: what about uln2803?

Comment: Same answer- the extra output does not buy you anything.

Comment: Listen to Spehro. Also note that there is a maximum total current for the chip as everything goes out on the common pin through one microscopic gold chip to lead-frame bonding wire.

Comment: i'll look for a mosfet alternative